# Statistical Significance for Bayesian parameter estimation

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, hierarchical-bayesian

I was reading a paper that estimated parameter using the Bayesian method. I am wondering how they can write the following statement based on the table below
"Two lane indicator is found to be statistically significant at 90% confidence interval" 
[image]

Comment: Well, that isn't really appropriate of them to say since "statistical significance", as it is understood in frequentism, doesn't really apply in Bayesianism.  I'm inclined to believe that whatever reference value the authors were using lied outside the 90% credible interval.

Comment: Could you share the source for this table? Without context this would be a guessing game.

Comment: This is the source: Ma, X., Chen, S., & Chen, F. (2017). Multivariate space-time modeling of crash frequencies by injury severity levels. Analytic Methods in Accident Research, 15, 29-40.